# How to include header in post request?

Tags: javascript, post, http-headers

I'm newb at Javascript. How do I include a header which I got from Fiddler to a post request I've made?

Here is my code which returns an error 403.

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = 'https://www.instagram.com/web/friendships/8752655712/unfollow/';
http.open('POST', url, true);

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
}
http.send();
```

Comment: Your code already includes code to set a request header. It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I want to include the specific header that I got from traffic sniffer. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: The same way as you are doing for the existing request header that you are setting

Answer (score -2):

You can set headers like this:

```
http.setRequestHeader(key, value);
```

replace key, value with the keys and values that you want.

**Update:**
If you have multiple keys and values, you can keep through an object like this

```
var headers = {
    "Key1": "value1",
    "Key2": "value2"
}

//then loop through headers object
for(var key in headers){
    //make sure that key exists in headers
    if(headers.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        http.setRequestHeader(key, headers[key]);
    }
}
```

Comment: But I have multiple key-headers. How do I include all of them?

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand. Could you give me an example?

Comment: `http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');`

Comment: But the header is 10 lines of text. How do I include it?

Comment: With a very long string

Comment: Instead of first or second parameter?

Comment: @sideshowbob --- If you have multiple key-headers, then just repeat ```setRequestHeader``` multiple times. If you have too many to hardcode, make an object full of key / values, then loop through them.

Comment: @sideshowbob — Try reading the documentation for `setRequestHeader` since you are using it already. You would need to replace both arguments.